# Valores dentro de um determinado intervalo

Tags: microsoft-excel

Quero fazer a seguinte formula mas não estou conseguindo. Não sei se é com `=SE()`, mas o que eu preciso é saber se um valor encontra-se dentro de um intervalo (de 1 a 2) ou não.

```
=SE(A1<=B1>=C1;1;0)
```

Se a célula A1 for menor ou igual a célula B1 e maior ou igual a célula C1 então deve dar 1, caso não, deve dar 0.

Essa formula dá erro, como faço para dar certo?

Answer (score 5):

Não é possível combinar dois operadores de comparação no teste de uma condição, para fazer isso é necessário utilizar a função `E()`.

```
=SE(E(A1<=B1;B1>=C1);1;0)
```

Comment: Ainda não deu certo. ele aparece como 0 quando deveria dar 1. O valor de A1 é 94,307 (é uma formula aplicada que pode variar conforme altero minha tabela) mas ele tem que ser menor que 94,570 ou maior que 94,573. Quando aplico sua formula ele aparece como resultado falso.

Comment: O que acontece?

Comment: É mais ou menos assim. Esta formula faz parte de um sistema que estou tentando calcular. Tenho 30 medições (cada uma representa uma media de outras 3 medições). Porem estas medias precisam estar fora de um determinado Limite de controle (que também é gerado por formula). Estes limites estão em 94,570....... e 94,573.... . Agora o que eu preciso é colocar uma formula que aponte quando esta verificação esta fora dos limites de controle ou dentro deles. Deu pra entender mais ou menos?

Comment: Math valeu pela ajuda!!! Consegui descobrir uma outra formula que se ajusta com base no que você mencionou. Agora sim ele calcula corretamente.        =SE(E(A1<B1);1;SE(E(A1>C1);1;0))

Comment: Desculpa a demora, eu estava em horário de almoço.

Comment: @Thiago acho que se fizesse =SE(E(A1<=B1;A1>=C1);1;0) também daria certo. A diferença é na segunda comparação que eu tinha usado B1>=C1, sendo que deveria ser A1 >= C1

Comment: eu tentei essa formula que você mencionou, e mesmo assim não calculava certo pois ele considerava os dois cálculos lógicos ao mesmo tempo, por isso ele me passava a resposta como falso todas as vezes. Quando eu separei e fiz por eliminação, ele começou a calcular certo, pois agora ele olha a primeira operação separado da segunda e consegue me informar quando o elemento esta ou não dentro do limite. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.